# Buscar os produtos mais vendidos (laravel / eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

No laravel, supondo que exista uma model 'Produto' (cuja tabela seja produtos), uma model 'Conta' (cuja tabela seja contas), e um relacionamento N:N entre contas e produtos, na tabela conta_produto, estou tentando achar uma maneira elegante de se buscar os 5 produtos mais vendidos usando relacionamentos do eloquent do laravel.

Eis o que eu possuo de código até o momento:

```
public function maisVendidos($quantidade)
    {

        $cp = ContaProduto::select('produto_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('produto_id')
            ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
            ->limit($quantidade)
            ->get();

        //inicializa um array de produtos + vendidos
        $produtos = [];

        //para cada ID encontrado, buscar o produto associado
        foreach($cp as $obj) {
            $produto = Produto::find($obj->produto_id);
            array_push($produtos, $produto);
        }

        return response()->json($produtos);
    }
```

Com certeza existe uma maneira de se relacionar através das models, mas não estou conseguindo achar na documentação uma maneira fácil de se fazer isso.

Alguém mais experiente possa dar uma ideia?

Obrigado!

EDIT:
As models são:

```
    <?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Categoria;
use App\Item;

class Produto extends Model {

    protected $table = 'produtos';  

    public function itens()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item');
    }

    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria');
    }

    public function contas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Conta');
    }
}

<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Produto;

class Conta extends Model {

    protected $table = 'contas';
    protected $attributes = array(
            'valor' => 0.0,
            'encerrada' => 0
        );

    public function mesa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Mesa');
    }

    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Produto');
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ContaProduto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'conta_produto';
}
```

Comment: Coloque os 3 `Models` na sua pergunta com todos os campos da tabela, você já fez algo diferente ( que ate funciona, sem problemas em relação em ter o model intermediário implicito )  pelo visto então fica dificil dizer sem ver o código dos `models` e tem um problema de desempenho.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Adicionei as três models. Acredito que não seja muito necessário todos os atributos, apenas as chaves que relacionam essas três models, que estão seguindo os padrões do laravel. Em outras palavras, produto possui um id (PK), conta possui um id (PK) e conta_produto possui a chave produto_id (FK) e conta_id (FK).

Comment: O campo total vem da onde?

Comment: Na verdade o total eh apenas um alias para o count(*). O count vai contar os registros agrupados no order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira seria a busca de todos os `id` de produtos na tabela `conta_produto` e utilizar método [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) para busca do `array` de `id` retornados, ***exemplo***:

```
public function maisVendidos($quantidade)
{
    $ids = ContaProduto::select('produto_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('produto_id')
            ->orderByRaw('count(*) DESC')
            ->limit($quantidade)
            ->pluck('produto_id');

    $produtos = Produto::whereIn('id', ids)->get();
    return response()->json($produtos);
}
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent - Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, é a que mais se aproximou do que eu queria. Só peço pra alterar o Produto::whereIn('id', ids) por DB::table('produtos')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get(); porque usar a model aqui não funcionou, tem que ser query builder mesmo. Obrigado!

Comment: @GabrielAugusto qual é o erro, porque é pra funcionar ! passe o erro?

Comment: @GabrielAugusto faltou um `get()` na minha resposta deve ser isso.

Comment: Realmente, foi só isso.